# Set number of columns (or rows) in a facetted plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a facetted plot like this:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = hp, y = mpg)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_grid(. ~ carb)
```

[image]
However, the graph is too wide to be clearly read.

I'd like to be able to take the three rightmost locations and place them under the three leftmost, i.e. the facets should be in three columns * two rows like this.

> ```
> 1   2   3
>
> 4   5   6
> ```

Is it possible to set the layout of the facets, i.e. to set number of columns (or rows) with `facet_grid()`?

The documentation on [facet_grid](http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/facet_grid.html) doesn't seem to indicate that it's possible.

Thanks for the help :-)

Answer (score 73, accepted):

You can use the `ncol` (or `nrow`) argument in `facet_wrap`:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = hp, y = mpg)) +
 geom_point()  +
 facet_wrap(~ carb, ncol = 3)
```

[image]

Comment: One observation - you can control the precise _order_ of the facets by making sure that the factors include the ordering information. Default is to have the factors have ascending alphabetical or numerical order, but that can be changed.

Comment: facet_wrap has it's limitation, it doesn't have a `space` argument